# Laravel list routes in the view

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes, laravel-5.4

How can I list routes specifically the api routes in my view?

For example These:

```
...api/user
...api/Information
```

The artisan command for example does list them like this:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your controller you can get the list of routes using `Artisan` facade. I assume all your `api` routes have `api` string in its path.:

```
public function showRoutes($request) {
    $routes = Artisan::call('route:list', ['--path' => 'api']);
    return view('your_view', compact('routes'));  
}
```

**Edit :**

You can also use `Route` facades `getRoutes` method.

```
$routes = [];
foreach (\Route::getRoutes()->getIterator() as $route){
    if (strpos($route->uri, 'api') !== false){
        $routes[] = $route->uri;
    }
}
return view('your_view', compact('routes'));
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late Reply I get this error `The "path" argument does not exist.`

Comment: Check the answer. `path` is optional parameter so you need to add `--path`.

Comment: ok error vanished, but if I `dd($routes)` I get a `0`, shouldn't it contain an error with my api routes

Comment: You can loop through the routes.

Comment: Something like this Returns all routes `$routes = app()->routes->getRoutes();` but I do not know how to filter that

Comment: One last question if you have time, do you know how to get more Information from the route? like if I run `route:list` it gives me more Information like method, Name, Action, Middleware. Or does that now work this way, never returned routes to a view so my question may seem odd?

Comment: If you `dd($route)` you will see all the information. Just pick whatever you want.